# Are truly generic lambda functions possible in Java?

Tags: java

```
   interface MyFunction {
      int operation(int a, int b);
   }
```

then I can do

```
  MyFunction addition = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
  MyFunction subtraction = (int a, int b) -> a - b;
```

If I want to define function between other types, I can do

```
   interface MyFunction<T,U,V> {
      V operation(T a, U b);
   }
```

But what if I want to define `MyFunction` to work with 3 arguments? (without creating another interface)